# RelativeLayout avoid text over images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set a layout, who is going to be used for each row of a `ListActivity`. each row contains a bulb icon on the left, a text in the center, then a pen icon on the right.

I cannot find a solution to avoid the text part in the center to pass over the 2 images if it to big.

Here is what I have got on screen :

[image: Actual Display]

When the text is to long it displayed over the *bulb icon* and *pen icon*

How do I need to modified my layout to avoid it?

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEquipementInfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/equipementImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/equipementName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/equipementEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="1sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/editEquipmentName"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 2 parameters for TextView :

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equipementImage"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/equipementEdit"
```

Comment: that do the trick, thank you. Just a comment for other users, the `ImageView` *equipementEdit* need to be define before the `TextView`, to be able to use `"@id/equipementEdit"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RelativeLayout` attribute `android:layout_below` which will :

> Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID.

So in your case you will have to use `android:layout_below="@id/equipementImage"` on your `TextView`.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but I don't want to place the text below the tow images but between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use **weight sum** in layout xml.

like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEquipementInfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this may solve your problem.